# Better performance: Multiple includes or preprocess data?

Tags: php, html, performance

What is the **best option**? (Performance on frequent requests permlink)

- Multiple access on data files (Several access to filesystem is a problem?):

```
readfile("meta-data.html");
readfile("header.html");
readfile("ads.html");
readfile("body-tags.html"); 
readfile("ads2.html");
readfile("profile-target-userA.html"); 
...
```

- Preprocess parts of the page with template and str_replace:

```
$file = file_get_contents("template.code"); 
$file = str_replace("<!-- meta-data -->", $new_meta_data, $file);
$file = str_replace("<!-- header-->", $new_header, $file);
... 
echo $file;
```

Other alternative methods are welcome.

Comment: file() returns an array, use file_get_contents() to return the contents of a file as a string instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your OS has an I/O cache, the second approach may very well wind up being slower.  Moving strings around in memory (which is what `str_replace` is going to do) can be  considerably more expensive than hitting the disk, especially when the files are currently cached by the OS.

However, you should be basing your template/view system on maintainability and flexibility, not just performance.  It's better to sacrifice a bit in terms of performance to produce more maintainable templates.

Usually, I see templates written as PHP files -- one would set a few variables and then `include()` the templates.  PHP will then execute them, which gives you quite a bit of flexibility in coding your views.  And, if a template file really is just HTML, `include()` will have the same effect as `readfile()`.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing one file is by definition faster than accessing multiple files, as long as they're on the same drive (but otherwise it wouldn't be a fair equasion, for example when one file is on a hard disk and the other files are on an SSD). The physical location of the file has to be looked up, the drive has to 'search' for it, which will cost more time for every file you include.

But you're talking microseconds here, so I smell premature optimalization.

Comment: Don't forget about the I/O cache.  If these files are read frequently, they will spend most of their time in the OS I/O cache and can be returned to the application without even hitting the disk.

Comment: True, but I assumed he wants to replace stuff in the sequentially read files too.